# Is the map into the terminal object an epimorphism?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $C$ be a category with a terminal object $1$. Is the unique arrow from an object into $1$ necessarily an epimorphism? If not, is it an epimorphism if $C$ is a topos?

Comment: What are the inconsistent definitions?

Comment: I misread something. Sorry.

Comment: Arrow $e$ to a terminal object is *constant*. For each parallel pair $(f,g)$ of arrows  you have $ef=eg$ (if they are defined).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No to both. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the topos $\mathbf{Set} \times \mathbf{Set}$ and consider the object $(\emptyset, 1)$; the terminal object in $\mathbf{Set} \times \mathbf{Set}$ is $(1, 1)$, but the unique morphism $(\emptyset, 1) \to (1, 1)$ is not an epimorphism. Note $(\emptyset, 1)$ is not an initial object either; if you allow that, then we have a counterexample even in $\mathbf{Set}$: the unique map $\emptyset \to 1$ is not a surjection.

Answer (score 10):

By duality, your question is equivalent to: Is every morphism from the initial object a monomorphism? No, for example in $\mathsf{CRing}$ with initial object $\mathbb{Z}$ this holds only for rings of characteristic $0$.

Comment: Accordingly, the unique morphism of schemes $X \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ doesn't have to be an epimorphism.